# haskell fmap . fmap function, function over two functors

Tags: haskell

I find myself more and more often doing something like that...

I have a function `f :: IO [a]` then I want to apply on it a function of type `g :: a -> b`, to get `IO [b]`.

The long way is:

```
x <- f
let y = fmap g x
```

Which I then shortened to:

```
x <- f
let y = g <$> x
```

and nowadays I rather do:

```
y <- fmap g <$> f
```

but then with the `Functor` laws, I can see that I can do even:

```
(<$$>) = fmap . fmap
y <- g <$$> f
```

and though I saw often mentions of this `fmap . fmap` I see it has no special binding in the base library, while it seems like a massively frequent idiom for me. I literally could use this all over the place! So now I wonder, am I not trying hard enough to write pure code and that's why I hit this more than more experienced haskell programmers... Or is there a more elegant way to achieve this that explains why this idiom is not used by others much?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am of the opinion (which seems to be rather unpopular among parts of the Haskell community) that you should write your code to express your intent clearly and follow the expectations of the reader, and *not* then algebraically refactor your code into an equivalent form which is "neater", but not any more clear.

In this case there doesn't seem to be any real meaning to the fact that you have two occurrences of fmap here. The fact that you are adjusting the result of an IO action is not logically conected to the fact that the adjustment happens to be mapping over a list. If you see the "`fmap . fmap` pattern" many times in your code, that's just because `fmap` is a quite common function.

If you write

```
    y <- g <$$> x      -- or any other made-up operator name
```

not only do you force your reader to learn an unfamiliar operator, but once they have learned it, they have to expand it to `y <- fmap g <$> x` anyways to understand what is happening, since you grouped two unrelated operations together.

The best form is your `y <- fmap g <$> x` (or even better, `y <- map g <$> x`), since it fits into a familiar pattern `var <- function <$> action`.

(By the way, you mentioned the Functor laws, but they are in no way relevant to any of the rewritings in your question, which just amount to expanding definitions.)

Comment: I agree with your unpopular opinion.

Comment: Your argument that `IO` and `[]` are not logically connected makes a lot of sense to me. But would you then be of the opinion that when the two functors are in fact logically connected, adding `(<$$>) = fmap.fmap` makes sense? For example in `toUpper <$$> ["abc", "cde"]`

Comment: Hi Reid,  would you ever want to do Ted talk on programming and math ?  I think people would be interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: If there was a established shortcut for `fmap . fmap`, it wouldn't be unfamiliar to other readers of the code. There is also `liftA`, `liftA2`, `liftA3`, I don't see how a `fmap2` and `fmap3` could hurt for "apply deeper into the structures".

Answer (score 4):

Well, what you have there is a *composition of functors*. The most widespread implementation of that concept – albeit not really as general as you might like – are *monad transformers*.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-List.html#v:ListT

```
f' :: ListT IO a
f' = ListT f
```

On that, you can simply use `fmap g`, to get a value `h' :: ListT IO b` that can with `runListT` then be evaluated as `IO [b]`.

Whether that wrapping and unwrapping is worthwhile depends on how many operations you do in a row, that can use the same composition. For some applications, monad transformers are just terrific; in other cases they just make stuff more clunky than it already is. `fmap . fmap` is actually not too bad, is it? Often I'd just stay with that.

Comment: Yes most of the time in my use I agree `fmap . fmap` is the more pragmatic/sensible choice over monad transformers. I just feel very tempted right now to define this `<$$>` and start using in all my projects (typing `fmap . fmap` or `fmap g <$>` just feels a shame if I can get the operator) but it's annoying to add one operator and not follow the conventions of the community... Would you actually type `fmap . fmap` if your code if you stumbled on that situation?

Comment: Well, I rather wouldn't call it [`<$$>`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%24%24%3E) at any rate. — Yes, indeed I would type `fmap . fmap` in an appropriate situation, or `fmap f <$>`. Might not be the most elegant thing possible, but it definitely works and is very readable. If this idiom piles up, I would switch to the transformer / functor composition.

Answer (score 4):

Functors (and applicatives) compose and [the `Compose` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#v:Compose) defines functor and applicative instances for the composition of two functors. This means you can wrap your `IO [a]` in a `Compose IO [] a` and apply `fmap` e.g.

```
import Data.Functor.Compose
getCompose $ fmap g $ Compose f
```

Comment: That's nice, I wasn't aware that `Compose` was also in the transformers package.

Comment: but that is more verbose than `fmap . fmap`, what is the advantage of that approach?

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery - This abstracts the lifting of `fmap`, `<*>` etc. over the inner functor/applicative (`[]` in this case). If you only have one function to lift then it's not going to be worth it, but if you have a few then it might.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery: it's only an advantage if you can “stay” in the composed functor for a while. For monads that's quite natural (e.g. an entire web application in Yesod's handler monads, which are defined as transformers). For functors that aren't monads or at least applicatives, it does indeed not make so much sense, because you can always merge multiple `fmap`s into a single one by the functor laws.

Answer (score 2):

I'm finding myself doing that often as well and find it really confusing. I found `liftM . map` easier to read than `fmap . fmap`.